# Better Way to Convert Array String to String Variable

Tags: java

is there any elegant/better way like for loop or else for me to convert array String content to string variable other than below example ?

Example:

other way instead of this :

```
String[] stringArray = {"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6",
                       "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12" };

String a1 = stringArray[0];
String a2 = stringArray[1];
String a3 = stringArray[2];
String a4 = stringArray[3];
String a5 = stringArray[4];
String a6 = stringArray[5];
String a7 = stringArray[6];
String a8 = stringArray[7];
String a9 = stringArray[8];
String a10 = stringArray[9];
String a11 = stringArray[10];
```

Comment: why you want to assign again to a1,a2 .just use stringArray[i]; when you need

Comment: Why do you want to use variables like that? It's not scalable. Use the array directly.

Comment: Go more into detail what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do it like that. A loop would allow you to use a single string instance to do multiple prints, for example.

Comment: if what you want is 11 String variable, you can't do it in loop, unless you want  to transform the array into one String variable by concatinaiting values

Comment: What is the purpose of `String a11 = "a11";`? How is it used? What is the end goal?

Comment: sorry guys, i think after reading all of your comment i admit that it is unnecessary actually. i cant recall why i was thinking i want to implement the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me **here is no answer for you**. The simpliest way is your code or using `stringArray[i]`.

You can not be everywhere and in everything elegant and impeccable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to deploy an array into several variables. In the case you want brand new variables, you will need to declare them, so you don't have many alternatives...

If those variables where existing and contained into a known object, you could use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the more elegant way is to avoid the use of the String variables `a1..a11` at all and to use `stringArray[i]` directly instead. You can define integer constants for the indices for more readable names.